# React Native: Inserting new object inside Array

Tags: react-native

after successfully implementing sockets, i can now listen to my event from one screen to another. My problem now is that i want to display the new object that i obtained inside my flatlist.

Here is the new msg object:

`messages: Object { "conversationId": 33, "message": "Heyy", "receiverId": 43, "senderId": 53, }`

Here is my code:

```
const [listings, setListings] = useState([]);

const loadListings = async () => {
setLoading(true);
const response = await messagesApi.getMessages();
setLoading(false);
if(refreshing) setRefreshing(false);
if (!response.ok) return setError(true);
setError(false);
setListings(response.data)
};

useEffect(() => {
const newsocket = sockets(user.id);
setSocket(newsocket);
newsocket.on("send_message", (msg) => {
  console.log("messages:", msg);
  setListings(listings => [...listings,msg]);
});
loadListings()
}, []);

return (
<FlatList
    data={listings}
    keyExtractor={(listing) => listing.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
      <MessagesList
      title={item.Listing.title}
        subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
        imageUrl={item.images[0].url}
        thumbnailUrl={item.images[0].thumbnailUrl}
        // onPress={() => console.log("message selected", item)}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT, 
                 {message:item,index,updateView,newsocket:socket})}
      />
    )}
  />
)
```

When i run this code i keep getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating listing.id.toString`.

I think i am getting this error since this new message object wants to get rendered live without getting it for database and hence it is still not given an id.

How do i go ahead and fix this?

***Additional info***

console.log(listings[0]) prints this

```
Object{ 
        "id":33,
       "Listing":{    
                  "title": "test",
                 },
       "Messages":Array[
                  Object {
                          "conversationId": 33,
                          "id": 601,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
                   Object {
                          "conversationId": 33,
                          "id": 600,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
                        ],
        "images":Array[
                 Object {"url":"","thumbnailUrl":""}]
      }
```

console.log(listings.map(x=>x.Messages))

```
 Array[
       Array[
                  Object {
                          "conversationId": 33,
                          "id": 601,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
                   Object {
                          "conversationId": 33,
                          "id": 600,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
            ],
      Array[
                  Object {
                          "conversationId": 1,
                          "id": 2,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
                   Object {
                          "conversationId": 1,
                          "id": 1,
                          "message": "Hey",
                          },
             ],
         ],
```

I also tried this

```
 useEffect(()=>{
 const x =listings.map(x=>x.id)
 console.log(x)
 },[listings])
```

this prints out the following:

```
Array [
32,
33,
29,
15,
27,
25,
26,
4,
17,
]
```

I just now need to check for the specific conversation before adding my msg object to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create you`keyExtractor` like

```
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
```

Comment: Hi Nooruddin i tried the code suggested and got `TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating item.Listing.title`

Comment: @kd12345 Try `{({ item, index })` instead of `{(item, index)`

Comment: @LeriGogsadze thank you so much for getting back to me. so i try this `keyExtractor={({ item, index }) => index.toString()}`?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze now i am getting `TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating index.toString`

Comment: I think i need to check for the conversationId first then add the messages object to the corresponding messages Array but my problem is that the messages object only conversationId,receiverId,senderId,message field only

Comment: Can you log item inside `renderItem` function?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze im getting [Function renderItem]

Comment: Log `item` not entire function.

Comment: please read carefully, log `item` inside `renderItem` function.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze i am almost there, how do i make it update that specific conversation and not add a new item to the flatlist?

Comment: Hi, hope all is well. Do you mind helping me out on this question, very much appreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199039/textinput-stops-working-in-my-entire-android-app

Answer (score 0):

You already have a variable `listing` and it is conflicting at `keyExtractor`.

change it like this

```
keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, i tried the code suggested and got `TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating item.id.toString`

Comment: try `return listings ? (<FlatList ... />): null`

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: and keep keyextractor as it is?

Comment: Error cannot find variable listing

Comment: my bad.. it should be `listings` =>  `return listings ?
(<FlatList
    data={listings}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item,index }) => (
      <MessagesList
      title={item.Listing.title}
        subTitle={item.Messages[0].message}
        imageUrl={item.images[0].url}
        thumbnailUrl={item.images[0].thumbnailUrl}
        // onPress={() => console.log("message selected", item)}
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CHAT, 
                 {message:item,index,updateView,newsocket:socket})}
      />
    )}
  />
): null`

Comment: error unexpected token and a red line under return